# Configure R in VS code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install R in VS code but failed . I have also Install extension of R in VS . also install R but Vs is giving me error " Linux can't user R.
Extension are :
**Vs Code R Extension on your Vs Code**
**R LSP Client on your VSCode**

Kindly let me know the solution .
[image]

Comment: Can you run `apt list --installed "r-*"` and update your question?

Comment: Listing is Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs when the R extension for VS Code can't automatically find your R executable.

Try adding the location of your R executable to your `settings.json` file (accessible using the `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` command):

```json
    "r.rpath.linux": "path/to/executable/for/r",
    "r.rterm.linux": "path/to/executable/for/r"
```

`r.rpath.linux` needs to be a 'normal' R executable. `r.rterm.linux` can be wrapper for R such as radian.

If you don't know where your R executable is you can find it by running this in a terminal:

```
which R
```

Comment: This works perfectly in my remote sessions as well! Great response and here is another [walkthrough](https://renkun.me/2019/12/11/writing-r-in-vscode-a-fresh-start/) that is extremely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to install R in VScode (macOS/Windows) in 2024:

1. Open vscode Open Extension section and download R extension

> Download Name: R
> Id: REditorSupport.r
> Description: R Extension for Visual Studio Code
> Version: 2.8.2
> Publisher: REditorSupport
> VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r

2. now open terminal and switch to R interactive terminal provided by R
   extension
3. run command `install.packages("languageserver")`